# How to use mixed models as t-test alternative when testing cumulative data for treatment differences?

Tags: t-test, lme4-nlme, glmm

I've been studying greenhouse gas fluxes in an aquarium experiment where water temperature changed over time (like outside). Treatments consisted of a control and a warmed (+3°C) situation. Measurements were performed fortnightly or monthly (the higher frequency measurements during biologically relevant seasons). In the end cumulative emissions of different greenhouse gases were determined by calculating the area under the curve of the measurements over time. To statistically analyze the treatment (warming) effect on these cumulative emissions I used a student's t-test. However, as I am concerned about the low power (each treatment only has n = 4) I'm looking for alternatives.

I tried using linear mixed models with treatment as fixed effect and time and aquarium as crossed random effects. A LRT was then used to test this model against an intercept only model (same random effects structure). However, I encountered two problems here:

1) Since measurement intervals were not constant, measurements with large intervals relatively outweigh measurements with small intervals in the calculation of cumulative emissions (since determined by area under curve). Does this mean that I should also take this into account in my mixed model? E.g. am I allowed to use the area under the curve between two consecutive measurements as an observation instead of using the values for each individual measurement?

2) For some of the measured greenhouse gases, the fitted vs. residual plots show clear violation of assumptions (e.g. non-linearity or heteroskedasticity) that cannot be resolved by transforming the data. Are GLMMs in this case the way to go?

Thanks for any help on this issue.